# Visual Basic: How can you go to the next line in a label with a for loop

Tags: vba, visual-studio

Im trying to figure out how to run through even numbers on a for loop and then print those numbers to a label in a windows form via a button. Currently, when I press the button it only displays 20. I believe the code is running through the loop and then when it gets to 20 it just prints 20. I need to print all the numbers in the label object.

Heres the current code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click

    For intEven = 2 To 20 Step 2
        lblEven.Text = intEven
    Next


End Sub
End Class
```

Heres a picture of the application when its ran:

[Running the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkIi7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

And I have just figured it out!

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click

    Dim intEven As Integer

    For intEven = 2 To 20 Step 2
        lblEven.Text = lblEven.Text &
            intEven.ToString & ControlChars.NewLine
    Next intEven


End Sub
End Class
```